# How to execute for / while loop within Intern test case framework

Tags: intern

How does one execute a for / while loop within Intern test case framework?  For instance, I have a drop-down list and I'd like to go through each list item, save configuration and re-enter config page to verify item.

Example:

```
    'verify Project Status drop-down test': function () {

        var projStatusList = ['Draft','Active','Archived'];


        return remote

            // for loop
            .then(function(){
              for(var i=0; i < projStatusList.length; i++){
                //console.info('list item: ' + projStatusList[i]);

                // open list

                // select list item

                // save page

                // re-enter config page

                // verify correct selected list item after save

                }
            })

            .end();

    }, // complete test case
```

Or is the answer to this similar to the Intermediate question '[Writing better functional tests with Page objects](https://gist.github.com/csnover/f80e370fe500b3dd6934)'

Note: I realize that there is a similar / duplicate question back on Aug. 2014 with no answer.

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
'verify project status': function () {
    var projStatusList = [ 'Draft', 'Active', 'Archived' ];
    return projStatusList.reduce(function (chain, status) {
        return chain
            .findByCssSelector(<list>)
            .click()
            .end()
            .findByCssSelector(<list item>)
            .click()
            .end()
            .findByCssSelector(<save button>)
            .click()
            .end()
            .sleep(1000)
            .findByCssSelector(<list item>)
            .end();
    }, remote);
}
```

Comment: what does  `chain` denote.

Comment: `chain` is a promise chain. The head of the chain is `remote`, which is passed into reduce. Each call of the reduce callback extends the chain. So the first call of reduce returns `remote.findByCssSelector(<list>).click()...`, and the second call is really returning `remote.findByCssSelector(<link>).click()...findByCssSelector(<list>).click()...`.